# Unknown plugin: imagemin-svgo using image-minimizer-webpack-plugin

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I use vue.config.js like this

```
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? config.plugins.push(
          new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
            test: /.(jpe?g|png|gif|tif|webp|svg|avif)$/i,
            include: undefined,
            exclude: undefined,
            filter: () => true,
            severityError: "error",

            minimizerOptions: {
              encodeOptions: {
                avif: {
                  cqLevel: 33,
                  cqAlphaLevel: -1,
                  subsample: 1,
                  tileColsLog2: 0,
                  tileRowsLog2: 0,
                  speed: 0,
                  chromaDeltaQ: false,
                  sharpness: 0,
                  denoiseLevel: 0,
                  tune: 0,
                },
              },
              plugins: ["svgo"],
            },

            loader: true,
            filename: "[path][name][ext]",
            deleteOriginalAssets: false,
          })
        )
      : console.log("\n Image compression skipped \n");
  },
})
```

but when I try to `yarn build`:

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js):
Unknown plugin: imagemin-svgo

Did you forget to install the plugin?
You can install it with:

$ npm install imagemin-svgo --save-dev
$ yarn add imagemin-svgo --dev
```

I tried to follow the only answer of this topic [WARNING in Unknown plugin: imageminSvgo. Did you forget to install the plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221676/warning-in-unknown-plugin-imageminsvgo-did-you-forget-to-install-the-plugin) but it didn't help,

installing this plugin didn't change anything, maybe there is an another way I can minimize svg and convert my images to avif...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is mixing syntaxes. `minimizerOptions` should be used when you're specifying ImageMinimizerPlugin.loader as a loader, probably something along these lines:

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: '...',
    use: {
      loader: ImageMinimizerPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        minimizerOptions: {
          plugins: ['svgo'] 
        }
      }
    } 
  }
]
```

When instantiating a `new ImageMinimizerPlugin({})`, the appropriate setting seems to use the keys `minimizer: { options: {...} }` to set the `encodeOptions` and `plugins` as in your example, according to the samples provided in the [official image-minimizer-webpack-plugin documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble. You need to set `loader: false` if you are only using the plugin.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/#standalone-plugin